# Cyrillic word error in Figure Captions

Tags: packages, cyrillic, russian

I used the package `\usepackage[russian]{babel}` to use some cyrillic words in my file. But now, instead of **Fig. 4: Figure Name**, figure's abbrevation seems in the cyrillic words not Latin words.

[image: attached file]

How can it be corrected?

Comment: Use `\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}`  and `\foreignlanguage{russian}{<russian words here>}` when you need it.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much. I did the things that you said. Now, although there are no errors, the russian words doesn' t appear (there is empty instead of them).

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of what you're doing?

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest.  I missed something just now, I solved the problem now:) ( by following the steps that @Johannes_B said)